# Issue upgrading to Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, redirect

I've recently upgraded my Magento version to 2.4.6. on my localhost. I installed it through Composer which indicates that everything has been successful. When I go to my local url, I get the browser message, 'This page isn't working' with the error code ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Also the url has redirected to [base_url]/pub/setup. I am running this on Windows 10.

Does anyone know what's going on here and know of a solution to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the answer to this so will post in case anyone else doesn't know. Magento 2 has ended the web install since version 2.4. This must now be done completely via command line. Once Composer has finish the install, you'll have to run a command similar to the below:

`magento setup:install --base-url="http://mylocaldomain/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admi
n" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="joe.bloggs@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_GB" --currency="GBP" --timezone="Europe/London" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="
admin"`

Answer (score 0):

- Please try to confirm whether the URLs in the core_config_table are
  correct or not.
- Check your nginx aur apache hosts.

If you need help please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think it's any of these things. The host is definitely correct as was able to reach the url before installing Magento. I've so far only installed the code base so there is no database tables yet. I am expecting a setup page to appear to allow me to do this.

Comment: When you are trying to install magento by command. The URL should be correct

Answer (score 0):

The ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error message indicates that the browser is stuck in an infinite redirect loop. This can be caused by a misconfiguration in the web server or a problem with the website's code. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Clear your browser cache and cookies. Sometimes cached data can cause the browser to get stuck in a redirect loop.
2. Check your web server configuration. Make sure that your web server is properly configured and that the document root is set correctly.
3. Check your Magento configuration. Make sure that your Magento installation is properly configured and that the base URL is set correctly. You can check this by looking at the app/etc/env.php file or a core_config_table in database.
4. Check your .htaccess file. Make sure that your .htaccess file is properly configured and that there are no rules that could be causing a redirect loop.
5. Check your Windows hosts file. Make sure that your Windows hosts file is properly configured and that there are no conflicting entries that could be causing a redirect loop.
6. Check your Magento cache. Try clearing your Magento cache by running the following command from your Magento root directory:

   php bin/magento cache:clean
7. Check your Magento logs. Check the Magento logs for any errors or warnings that could be related to the redirect loop. You can find the logs in the var/log directory.

Hopefully, one of these steps will help you resolve the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error message.